# Returning a function acting on an array

Tags: python, numpy

Consider a function getf taking a numpy array a and integer b. I want to return a callable function f such that f has  value  0  for a< b and a>b and value 1 for a=b.

Something like

```
  getf(a,b):
     if a< b & b>a:
         return 0 
     else:
         return 1
```

does not work.

How do I can ensure that my return value is a function?

Example

```
 a = [1,2,3,4,5]
 b=2
```

return function with result array [0,1,0,0,0]

Comment: first of all, & is not a logical AND in Python

Comment: `a<b` and `b>a` are unclear given that `a` is a numpy array and `b` an integer. Can you give some sample input and output? Similarly, `a=b` is very unclear.

Comment: Functions are objects in Python and can be returned, hope this helps =>https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-return-statement/#:~:text=In%20Python%2C%20functions%20are%20objects,first%20class%20objects%20in%20Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you need this, but this code defines a function and returns it, which can be called with two keyword arguments.

```
def  getf():
    def f(a, b):
        return [int(b==i) for i in a]
        
    return f
    
print(getf()(a = [1,2,3,4,5], b=2))
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of that a function can be returned in that way.

Comment: "*Consider a function getf taking a numpy array a and integer b*" this is not what this function is doing. Good it this is what you wanted, but you should make your use case more explicit ;)

Comment: Obviously, this function *can* take `a` and `b` and do nothing with them. But I do agree that the question is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use vectorial code, not return a scalar. Also, use a numpy array for `a`.

Finally, your conditions were incorrect (you had twice the same condition). I imagine you want to check if a is greater of equal b and lower or equal b (which is a == b, but let's keep it like this for the sake of the example).

```
def getf(a,b):
    return ((a >= b) & (b >= a)).astype(int)

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b = 2

getf(a, b)
# array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not return a callable function?

Comment: @StevenHunt you need to provide a better example of what you expect. What should the returned function look like?